# How to do multi-label classification in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, mahout

I want to do a multi-label text classification on a big data set set and it seems like that big data machine learning tools such as Apache Mahout or Spark MLLib are not currently support that. I would like to know has any one done a multi-label classification for big data sets before? Are there any plan to integrate multi-label classification in either Mahout or Spark in the near future?

Answer (score 0):

This [paper](http://souhaib-bentaieb.com/pdf/2010_neuro.pdf) addresses the nature of the benefits you would receive from multioutput forecasting... namely:

1. The ability to account for multiple independent input parameters when making a prediction, rather than having to continuously update your metrics for each nth index prediction your are trying to make within a given forecast.
2. Computational speed is increased.

Based on your need - I would recommend trying to down-sample to a smaller group for your current problem and then create multiple models around bespoke groups within your dataset if performance does not match what you are looking for.

I am still encountering this challenge myself (4 years since your post...).

Here is a list of helpful articles that I have collected while trying to address this:

- [Long-term forecasting with machine learning models](https://thuijskens.github.io/2016/08/03/time-series-forecasting/)
- [Sorry ARIMA, but I’m Going Bayesian](https://multithreaded.stitchfix.com/blog/2016/04/21/forget-arima/)
- [Multiple-Output Modelling for Multi-Step-Ahead Time Series
  Forecasting](http://souhaib-bentaieb.com/pdf/2010_neuro.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Can we first transform the labels into a class, and then after prediction, transform it back to the original label? for example, i have 3 labels to predict, `[y1, y2, y3]`. if `[y1, y2, y3] = [1, 0, 1]`, then i give it `label = 101 = 5`. And during prediction, I predicted the probability of y1 in the following way:
`p(y1=1) = p(100) + p(101) + p(110) + p(111)`. In this way a multi label problem  became a multilabel problem